# Making a split header with a logo in the middle

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to design a menu where the menu is split in two pieces with a logo in the middle.

I have it working out either one of two ways right now:

Either A, the logo div sits on top and makes the menu unclickable, like so:

[image]

Or B, the menu sits on top and makes part of the logo unclickable.

[image]

You can [see a live example here](http://jsfiddle.net/jSgYh/4/embedded/result/). (I used the second example. Notice how you can't click on Google logo when your cursor is aligned with menu bar)

And [here is the source](http://jsfiddle.net/jSgYh/4/).

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

How can I design a menu that allows for this to flow better and still be functional?

Comment: When the widths of the menu items aren't equal you most likely need to do calculations with JavaScript to determine after which menu-item the log will have to come to be in the middle of the section.

Comment: Try something like this; http://jsfiddle.net/Allendar/jSgYh/9/. It's not very precise, but can almost pinpoint how to split the items in the middle. The `rest_width` tweaking/calculation needs tweaking tho. Try fiddle around with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 26px;
  margin-left: 0 auto;
  margin-top:50px;
  z-index:9999;
}
#logo {
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  width:232px;
  top:30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 10000;
}
```

Can something like this not work? http://jsfiddle.net/jSgYh/6/